# bug with "Extract Android String" option in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having trouble using the refactor feature in eclipse (Indigo on Win7 64) to move my hard coded strings to the string.xml file.

[Automatic Code Generation for Strings.xml from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631661/automatic-code-generation-for-strings-xml-from-eclipse)

It creates the entry in string.xml ok but when it builds the appropriate code, part of the code can be duplicated and the resulting code is nonsense. For example:

```
...setText("Inbox")
```

becomes:

```
...setText(R.string.inboxg.inbox)
```

instead of

```
...setText(R.string.inbox)
```

This behavior varies depending on the length of the line and what is being replaced.

Anyone seen this before, know of a fix?

Comment: I've had this same thing happen to me before.  It only happened on one string, and I manually renamed it.  It occurred after refactoring the package name...  so a little different but it did the same concatenation of the half-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a very similar occurrence happen to me when refactoring the package name.  I can't really see a way to fix this (besides a global find and replace), perhaps an issue needs to be submitted:

Android google code issue repository:

> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

I've done a quick search through the issues and couldn't find anything related.